# RtlCopyMemory never returns, lags out PC

Tags: windows, kernel, windows-kernel

I'm trying to read a char array, then write it to another process in a kernel driver. In order to do so I need to copy the char array that I read from OtherProcess then write it to MyProcess. The issue is whenever the driver reaches RtlCopyMemory, it gets stuck and never returns. It also lags the hell out of my PC while it's stuck.

```
    unsigned char* tempBytes;
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(KeReadProcessMemory(myProcess, (PVOID)ReadByteArrayRequest.Address, (PVOID)&tempBytes, ReadByteArrayRequest.bytes))) {
        log("Could not read byte array at address: %i with %i bytes", ReadByteArrayRequest.Address, ReadByteArrayRequest.bytes);
        return STATUS_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    ReadByteArrayRequest._return = (unsigned char*)ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, ReadByteArrayRequest.bytes); // alternative to malloc

    RtlCopyMemory((void*)ReadByteArrayRequest._return, tempBytes, ReadByteArrayRequest.bytes); // driver gets stuck on this & lags out pc

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Write<KeReadByteArrayRequest>(myOtherProcess, READ_BYTE_ARRAY_REQUEST, ReadByteArrayRequest))) {
        log("There was an error when sending response for ReadByteArrayRequest");
        return STATUS_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    ExFreePool((PVOID)ReadByteArrayRequest._return); // we can't use free
```

Comment: Could this be maybe caused by i'm allocating the ptr incorrectly with ExAllocatePool?

Comment: Where are you calling it from? Is this a buffered I/O request from user mode? You should set the memory to NonPagedPool instead.